# Get proper list from list of unicode list

Tags: python, list, unicode, unicode-escapes

I have a list with a unicode string in a form of a list.

```
my_list = [u'[James, Williams, Kevin, Parker, Alex, Emma, Katie\xa0, Annie]']
```

I want a list which I am able to iterate such as;

```
name_list = [James, Williams, Kevin, Parker, Alex, Emma, Katie, Annie]
```

I have tried several possible solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20), but none of them worked in my case.

```
# Tried
name_list =  name_list.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')

#Gives unicode return type

# Tried
ast.literal_eval(name_list)

#Gives me invalid token error
```

Comment: If you are only just learning Python, you should ignore Python 2. The currently supported and recommended version of the language is Python 3.

Comment: `name_list = [James, Williams...` is illegal in Python. What you want is `name_list = ['James', 'Williams'...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, a list does not have a `encode` method, you have to apply any string methods on the item in the list.

Secondly, if you are looking at normalizing the string, you can use the `normalize` function from Python's `unicodedata` library, read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize), this removes the unwanted characters `'\xa0'` and will help you normalize any other characters.

Then instead of using `eval` which is generally unsafe, use a list comprehension to build a list:

```
import unicodedata

li = [u'[James, Williams, Kevin, Parker, Alex, Emma, Katie\xa0, Annie]']
inner_li = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", li[0]) #<--- notice the list selection

#get only part of the string you want to convert into a list
new_li = [i.strip() for i in inner_li[1:-1].split(',')] 
new_li
>> ['James', 'Williams', 'Kevin', 'Parker', 'Alex', 'Emma', 'Katie', 'Annie']
```

In your expected output, they are actually a list of variables, which unless declared before, will give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
import unicodedata

lst = [u'[James, Williams, Kevin, Parker, Alex, Emma, Katie\xa0, Annie]']
lst = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", lst[0])
lst2 = lst[1:-1].split(", ") # remove open and close brackets
print(lst2)
```

output will be:

```
["James", "Williams", "Kevin", "Parker", "Alex", "Emma", "Katie ", "Annie"]
```

if you want to remove all spaces leading/trailing whitespaces:

```
lst3 = [i.strip() for i in lst2]
print(lst3)
```

output will be:

```
["James", "Williams", "Kevin", "Parker", "Alex", "Emma", "Katie", "Annie"]
```

Comment: tried above lst2 = list[0][1:-1].split(", "), but it gives an error of "list index out of range".

Comment: Yes i tried the same.. i  have used proper  variable name.

Comment: sorry it worked now.!! thank you. Not sure why for first run it gave error.
But it gives me a list of unicode  names, [u'James', u'Williams', u'Kevin', u'Parker', u'Alex', u'Emma', u'Katie\xa0', u'Annie'].
While printing when it comes to 'Katie\xa0' it throws UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0'

Comment: @Rachel you can use `unicodedata.normalize` as BernardL mentioned. `lst[0] = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", lst[0])`

Comment: I've added more explanation

Answer (score 0):

This is a good application for regular expressions:

```
import re
body = re.findall(r"\[\s*(.+)\s*]", my_list[0])[0] # extract the stuff in []s
names = re.split("\s*,\s*", body) # extract the names
#['James', 'Williams', 'Kevin', 'Parker', 'Alex', 'Emma', 'Katie', 'Annie']
```

Comment: Um, why is this a good application for regular expressions? If the input is regular in the first place, just `names = value.strip('[]').split(', ')`

Comment: @tripleee For starters, your solution does not remove '\xa0'. As a follow-up, regular expressions take care of all possible stray spaces before and after commas and brackets. Finally, you are welcome to post your answer separately.

Comment: If the input *isn't* regular, why is `\xa0` something we specifically worry about? How about other junk and typos? Anyway, the question is just too unclear to deserve answering IMHO.

Comment: @tripleee Firstly, because the OP explicitly requested to have it removed. Secondly, because `\xa0` _is_ a whitespace, and my solution does remove all white spaces.